# How do I set a parameter based on a condition using LINQ and Entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

**This is my code:**

```
await ctx.Education.AsNoTracking()
        .Where(e => e.EmployeeNumber == employeeNumber)
        .Select(e => new EducationDTO {
                Id = e.EducationID,
                StartDate =  DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(e.EducationEntryYear , 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) ?? DateTime.Now,
                EndDate = DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(e.EducationGraduationYear, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
        })
        .ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

In some cases "e.EducationEntryYear" is 0, which as a result  returns this exception `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

What is the simplest way to have first parameter as current year, in case `e.EducationEntryYear` is 0

Comment: Just replace `e.EducationEntryYear` with `e.EducationEntryYear == 0 ? DateTime.Now.Year : e.EducationEntryYear`

Comment: have you tried e.EducationEntryYear >0?e.EducationEntryYear: 2016 ?

Comment: You'll have to save DateTime.Now.Year to a variable first

Comment: *In some cases "e.EducationEntryYear" is 0* - Just curious - in what cases will this be '0'?  What does field represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the conditional (`?`) operator.

```
await ctx.Education.AsNoTracking()
        .Where(e => e.EmployeeNumber == employeeNumber)
        .Select(e => new EducationDTO {
                Id = e.EducationID,
                StartDate =  DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(e.EducationEntryYear == 0 ? DateTime.Now.Year : e.EducationEntryYear, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0) ?? DateTime.Now,
                EndDate = DbFunctions.CreateDateTime(e.EducationGraduationYear, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
        })
        .ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Where you currently have

```
e.EducationEntryYear
```

Replace it with

```
e.EducationEntryYear == 0 ? System.DateTime.Now.Year : e.EducationEntryYear
```